# cluetip jquery plugin : how can show laoding image inside the tooltip popup

Tags: php, jquery

I am using cluetip jquery plugin and I want to show laoding image inside the tooltip popup.

Just like facebook do. It shows a "loading..." text inside the popup window and then show the data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an demo which can help you

> **My root folder contains the following files**

- index.html
- demo.html
- jquery.cluetip.css
- jquery.cluetip.js
- jquery.min.js
- Koala.jpg

My index.html has the following code

```
 <html >
    <head>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.cluetip.css" type="text/css" />
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script> 
      <script src="jquery.cluetip.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function() {
             $('a.sticky').cluetip();
             $('#sticky').cluetip({
               arrows: true,
               sticky: true,
               tracking: true,
               mouseOutClose: true,
               closePosition: 'title',    
               cursor: 'pointer'
             });
           });
      </script>
     </head>

      <body >

       <strong>Demo for tooptip</strong> <br>
      <a id="sticky" href="#" rel="demo.html" title="Demo">ToopTip with arrows</a>

      </body>
      </html>
```

Here is the code for demo.html

```
  <html >
     <head>
     </head>
   <body class="page">

  <img src="Koala.jpg" width="65" height="65" alt="Koala" />
  <p>The koala is an arboreal herbivorous marsupial native to Australia, and the only extant representative of the family Phascolarctidae.</p>

    </body>
  </html>
```

Now open the index.html page and get the **clueTip** working